# Handle firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have the following functions:

```
function isAdded(el){
    if(!$(el).closest('tr').hasClass('cloned')){
      $(el).closest('tr').addClass('cloned');
      var row_variant_index = $("#items tbody tr.variant").index($(el).closest('tr'));
      $(el).closest('tr').attr('data-index',row_variant_index);
      var clone = $(el).closest('tr').clone(true);
      clone.find('button').remove();
      clone.find('td').last().prepend("<button name='delete'>x</button>"," ","<button name='decrement'>-</button>").append("<button name='increment'>+</button>");
      clone.appendTo('#cloned-items tbody');
    }
}

function handleButton(el){
  var input_box = $(el).siblings('input');
  switch ($(el).attr('name')){
    case 'decrement':
      if(parseInt($(input_box).val()) > 0){
        $(input_box).val(parseInt($(input_box).val() - 1));
      }
      break;
    case 'increment':
      $(input_box).val(parseInt($(input_box).val() + 1));
      break;
  }
}
```

These functions are being used in this handle:

```
$("button[name='addItem']").click(function(){
    if (!$(this).siblings('input').val().match(/\d+/)){
      alert("You can only type numbers!");
      return;
    }
    isAdded(this);
    $("#cloned-items tbody").on('click',"button",function(){handleButton(this)});
  });
```

My problem is that if I add more than 1 cloned item, the button begins adding or subtracting n+1 times ( If I have 2 clones it will add or subtract 2, if I have 3 it will add or subtract 3 and so on ).

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A quick fiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is you are adding new event listener

```
$("#cloned-items tbody").on('click',"button",function(){handleButton(this)});
```

everytime you click the button

So you simply need to make sure you don't call it again after another click

**Edit**

As pointed out by @JeremyJStarcher you can use `off()` function to remove previously added handlers.

```
$("#cloned-items tbody").off().on('click',"button",function(){handleButton(this)});
```

Comment: `  $("#cloned-items tbody").off().on('click',"button",function(){handleButton(this)});`  works as well.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Nice I never used `off()` :)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include the `off()` or is Jeremy answering? It worked.. I didn't know you could have repeated handles for an element.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation only needs to be done once, not every time you add another element to the DOM. That's what makes it different from normal event binding, it will be found dynamically on any element that matches the selector within the element that you delegated from. So take

```
$("#cloned-items tbody").on('click',"button",function(){handleButton(this)});
```

out of the `click()` handler, and just do it once in the `$(document).ready()` handler.